# Does test order affect performance result?

Tags: java, kotlin, junit

I wrote 2 blocks of time measurement code. The print result of *t1* is always much bigger than *t2*.
Block1 and block2 do the exact same thing. If I write block 2 before block1, then The print result of *t2* is much lesser than *t1*.
I wonder why this happens.

```
@Test
fun test(){
    val list = (1..100000).toList()

    //block 1
    var t1 = System.nanoTime()
    list.filter { it % 7 == 0 }
    t1 = System.nanoTime() - t1

    //block 2
    var t2 = System.nanoTime()
    list.filter { it % 7 == 0  }
    t2 = System.nanoTime() - t2

    //print
    println(t1)
    println(t2)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing is called the warmup. The first requests made to a Kotlin (and other JVm based languages) is often substantially slower than the average response time. This warm-up period is caused by lazy class loading and just-in-time compilation.

There are a few ways how to measure performance more reliably. One of them is to create a warmup manually before the test itself is executed. Even more reliable method would be to use a specialized library such as [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Example of manual warmup:

```
// warmup
for (i in 1..9999) {
    val list = (1..100000).toList()
    list.filter { it % 7 == 0 }
}

// rest of the test
```

As a side note, Kotlin has built-it functions which you can use instead of manually calculating the time difference. There are [measureTimeMillis](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-time-millis.html) and [measureNanoTime](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-nano-time.html).

It would be used like this:

```
val time = measureNanoTime {
    list.filter { it % 7 == 0 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dose warmup generally exist in other languages? (except JVM's)

Comment: I am not aware of any on the scale of JVM. Generally any environment leveraging Just-In-Time compilation or Lazy-Loading will have some kind of warm up.